# Rspec let() cleanup

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to keep track of variables that are created when using let?

I have a series of tests, some of which use let(:server) { #blah blah }. Part of the blah is to wait for the server to start up so that it is in a decent state before it is used.

The issue comes when I'm done with that test. I want to kill the server using server.kill(). This would be almost perfect if I could say something to the effect of

```
after(:each) { server.kill }
```

But this would create the server and waste all the resources/time to create it when it is referenced, only to kill it immediately if the server hadn't been used in the preceding test. Is there a way to keep track of and only clean up the server if it has been used?

Answer (score 4):

I've come across a similar problem. A simple way to solve this is to set a instance variable in the let method to track if the object was created:

```
describe MyTest do

  before(:each) { @created_server = false }

  let(:server) { 
    @created_server = true
    Server.new 
  }

  after(:each) { server.kill if @created_server }

end
```

Comment: I love this method. Thanks for sharing it. I used it to teardown some models that got added to the db during tests but didn't get deleted after the test run.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is something like this:

```
describe MyTest do
  let(:server) { Server.new }

  context "without server" do
    ## dont kill the server in here.
  end

  context "with server" do

   before do
     server
   end

   after(:each) { server.kill }

   it {}
   it {}
  end
end
```

Comment: I could do something similar, but instead of having the let(:server) {} be in the top level describe block, move it to the "with server" context, remove the before(:each) {} and then the after(:each} {} would work...

Comment: @MichaelPapile: let block is called only once in the context, so the after block should work just fine.

Comment: @MichaelPapile: I was having issues with let() before, and needing some of a let()'s side effects to exist, but not existing yet, because the let() that caused it hadn't been referenced yet. I used a workaround before I knew about let!() in which I had a before(:each) block that simply consisted of the name of the offending let(), meaning that the context of the let() extends to include the before(:each) block for that test, and should reasonably include the after(:each) block as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a hack:

```
describe "cleanup for let" do
  let(:expensive_object) {
    ExpensiveObject.new
  }
  after(:context) {
    v = __memoized[:expensive_object]
    v.close if v
  }
end
```

I figured that rspec had to be storing these lazy values somewhere the instance could access them, and `__memoized` is that place.

With a helper, it becomes a bit tidier:

```
def cleanup(name, &block)
  after(:context) do
    v = __memoized[name]
    instance_exec(v, &block) if v
  end
end

describe "cleanup for let" do
  let(:expensive_object) {
    ExpensiveObject.new
  }
  cleanup(:expensive_object) { |v|
    v.close
  }
end
```

There's still room for improvement, though. I think I would rather not have to type the object's name twice, so something like this would be nicer:

```
describe "cleanup for let" do
  let(:expensive_object) {
    ExpensiveObject.new
  }.cleanup { |v|
    v.close
  }
end
```

I'm not sure I can do that without hacking rspec to pieces, but maybe if rspec themselves saw the benefit of it, something could be done in core...

*Edit:* Changed to using `instance_exec` because rspec started whining if things were called from the wrong context, and changed cleanup to be `after(:context)`, because apparently this is the level it's memoising at.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a small decorator to handle both the explicit and implicit starting of the server and which allows you to determine if the server has been started.

Imagine this to be the real server that needs to be started:

```
class TheActualServer
  def initialize
    puts 'Server starting'
  end

  def operation1
    1
  end

  def operation2
    2
  end

  def kill
    puts 'Server stopped'
  end
end
```

The reusable decorator could look like this:

```
class ServiceWrapper < BasicObject
  def initialize(&start_procedure)
    @start_procedure = start_procedure
  end

  def started?
    !!@instance
  end

  def instance
    @instance ||= @start_procedure.call
  end

  alias start instance

  private

  def method_missing(method_name, *arguments)
    instance.public_send(method_name, *arguments)
  end

  def respond_to?(method_name)
    super || instance.respond_to?(method_name)
  end
end
```

Now you can apply this in your specs like the following:

```
describe 'something' do
  let(:server) do
    ServiceWrapper.new { TheActualServer.new }
  end

  specify { expect(server.operation1).to eql 1 }
  specify { expect(server.operation2).to eql 2 }
  specify { expect(123).to be_a Numeric }

  context 'when server is running' do
    before(:each) { server.start }

    specify { expect('abc').to be_a String }
    specify { expect(/abc/).to be_a Regexp }
  end

  after(:each) { server.kill if server.started? }
end
```

When a method is called on the decorator, it will run it's own implementation if one exists. For example if `#started?` is called, it will answer whether the actual server has been started or not. If it doesn't have an own implementation of that method, it will delegate the method call to the server object returned by that. If it doesn't have a reference to an instance of the actual server at that point, it will run the provided `start_procedure` to get one and memoize that for future calls.

If you put all the posted code into a file called `server_spec.rb` you can then run it with:

```
rspec server_spec.rb
```

The output will be like this:

```
something
Server starting
Server stopped
  should eql 1
Server starting
Server stopped
  should eql 2
  should be a kind of Numeric
  when server is running
Server starting
Server stopped
    should be a kind of String
Server starting
Server stopped
    should be a kind of Regexp

Finished in 0.00165 seconds (files took 0.07534 seconds to load)
5 examples, 0 failures
```

Note that in the examples 1 and 2, methods on the server are called, and therefore you see the output of the server that is implicitly started by the decorator.

In example 3 there is no interaction with the server at all, therefore you don't see the server's output in the log.

Then again in examples 4 and 5, there is not direct interaction with the server object in the example code, but the server is explicitly started through a before block, which can also be seen in the output.